# Is there an alternative to JobScheduler in iOS?

Tags: ios

In Android there is [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) where you can schedule to execute part of your code (service) when conditions are met. For example, if one wants to synchronise data, he can schedule a task when there is network connection available and the phone is charging. The service will be called even if the app is never opened after phone restart.

Is there a way how to do this in iOS? For example, how dropbox, onedrive, etc. uploads pictures to the cloud even when the app is not opened after a restart?

Comment: You can use background fetch, but there is no way to schedule an operation for a particular time. The operating system will just launch your app in the background periodically.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Did any of the options below work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if what you are asking for is possible: launching an scheduler event though the app has not been launch after phone restart.

Anyway, this library could be a solution for background synchronization tasks: https://github.com/linkedin/Selene and here a complete guide: https://engineering.linkedin.com/ios/introducing-selene-open-source-library-scheduling-tasks-ios

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `SwiftQueue` to see if it meets your needs.

https://github.com/lucas34/SwiftQueue

> `SwiftQueue` is a job scheduler for iOS inspired by popular android
>   libraries like android-priority-jobqueue or android-job. It allows you
>   to run your tasks with run and retry constraints.

---

> #### Features
>
> - Sequential execution
> - Concurrent run
> - Persistence
> - Cancel all, by id or by tag
> - Delay
> - Deadline
> - Internet constraint
> - Single instance in queue
> - Retry: Max count, exponential backoff
> - Periodic: Max run, interval delay
> - Start / Stop queue

They also have a [Battery charging constraint](https://github.com/lucas34/SwiftQueue/blob/master/Sources/SwiftQueue/Constraint%2BCharging.swift) that's not listed in the features above.